# A Non Numeric Value Encountered When Trying To Return Data URL PHP

Tags: php

I am currently trying to present a screen shot of a webpage after a user inputs a custom url. I am using google api pagespeedonline to grab the contents of the page as well as fetch the actual data url but when i go to return it on my backend I cant get it to successfuly return just the data url. My current code for doing so is:

```
public function web_preview(Request $request)
    {
        try {
            $url = $this->check_url($request->input('url'));
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            return $this->badRequestResponse($e->getMessage());
        }

        $info = $this->curl_file_info($url, $this::$ACCEPTABLE_HTML);
        if (!$this->is_textual($info))
            return $this->clientErrorResponse("Nontextual web asset");
        if ($info["http_code"] !== 200)
            return $this->clientErrorResponse("URL returned ",$info["http_code"]);

        try {
            $curl_init = curl_init(
                "https://www.googleapis.com/pagespeedonline/v5/runPagespeed?url=" + $url + "&key=AIzaSyCxGGWVSSY3fau3cPekSaY765XKRKHerNY&screenshot=true");
            curl_setopt($curl_init, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
            $response = curl_exec($curl_init);
            curl_close($curl_init);
            //call Google PageSpeed Insights API
            //decode json data
            $googlepsdata = json_decode($response);
            //screenshot data
            $snap = $googlepsdata['screenshot-thumbnails']['details']['data'];

        } catch(\Exception $e) {
            return $this->internalServerError($e->getMessage());
        }
        // $img = Image::make($snap);
        return $snap;
    }
```

and the curl_init should return this:

```
{
  "captchaResult": "CAPTCHA_NOT_NEEDED",
  "kind": "pagespeedonline#result",
  "id": "https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Basics_of_HTTP/Data_URIs",
  "loadingExperience": {
    "id": "https://developer.mozilla.org",
    "metrics": {
      "CUMULATIVE_LAYOUT_SHIFT_SCORE": {
        "percentile": 0,
        "distributions": [
          {
            "min": 0,
            "max": 10,
            "proportion": 0.97998381341452667
          },
          {
            "min": 10,
            "max": 25,
            "proportion": 0.01036026216807024
          },
          {
            "min": 25,
            "proportion": 0.00965592441740298
          }
        ],
        "category": "FAST"
      },
      "LARGEST_CONTENTFUL_PAINT_MS": {
        "percentile": 1415,
        "distributions": [
          {
            "min": 0,
            "max": 2500,
            "proportion": 0.92849265950201776
          },
          {
            "min": 2500,
            "max": 4000,
            "proportion": 0.046497587955101477
          },
          {
            "min": 4000,
            "proportion": 0.025009752542881025
          }
        ],
        "category": "FAST"
      },
      "FIRST_INPUT_DELAY_MS": {
        "percentile": 3,
        "distributions": [
          {
            "min": 0,
            "max": 100,
            "proportion": 0.99082487343845982
          },
          {
            "min": 100,
            "max": 300,
            "proportion": 0.005724879537811014
          },
          {
            "min": 300,
            "proportion": 0.0034502470237293141
          }
        ],
        "category": "FAST"
      },
      "FIRST_CONTENTFUL_PAINT_MS": {
        "percentile": 1386,
        "distributions": [
          {
            "min": 0,
            "max": 1000,
            "proportion": 0.55192771567034826
          },
          {
            "min": 1000,
            "max": 3000,
            "proportion": 0.4031506848279558
          },
          {
            "min": 3000,
            "proportion": 0.044921599501695914
          }
        ],
        "category": "AVERAGE"
      }
    },
    "overall_category": "AVERAGE",
    "initial_url": "https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Basics_of_HTTP/Data_URIs",
    "origin_fallback": true
  },
  "originLoadingExperience": {
    "id": "https://developer.mozilla.org",
    "metrics": {
      "CUMULATIVE_LAYOUT_SHIFT_SCORE": {
        "percentile": 0,
        "distributions": [
          {
            "min": 0,
            "max": 10,
            "proportion": 0.97998381341452667
          },
          {
            "min": 10,
            "max": 25,
            "proportion": 0.01036026216807024
          },
          {
            "min": 25,
            "proportion": 0.00965592441740298
          }
        ],
        "category": "FAST"
      },
      "LARGEST_CONTENTFUL_PAINT_MS": {
        "percentile": 1415,
        "distributions": [
          {
            "min": 0,
            "max": 2500,
            "proportion": 0.92849265950201776
          },
          {
            "min": 2500,
            "max": 4000,
            "proportion": 0.046497587955101477
          },
          {
            "min": 4000,
            "proportion": 0.025009752542881025
          }
        ],
        "category": "FAST"
      },
      "FIRST_INPUT_DELAY_MS": {
        "percentile": 3,
        "distributions": [
          {
            "min": 0,
            "max": 100,
            "proportion": 0.99082487343845982
          },
          {
            "min": 100,
            "max": 300,
            "proportion": 0.005724879537811014
          },
          {
            "min": 300,
            "proportion": 0.0034502470237293141
          }
        ],
        "category": "FAST"
      },
      "FIRST_CONTENTFUL_PAINT_MS": {
        "percentile": 1386,
        "distributions": [
          {
            "min": 0,
            "max": 1000,
            "proportion": 0.55192771567034826
          },
          {
            "min": 1000,
            "max": 3000,
            "proportion": 0.4031506848279558
          },
          {
            "min": 3000,
            "proportion": 0.044921599501695914
          }
        ],
        "category": "AVERAGE"
      }
    },
    "overall_category": "AVERAGE",
    "initial_url": "https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Basics_of_HTTP/Data_URIs"
  },
  "lighthouseResult": {
    "requestedUrl": "https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Basics_of_HTTP/Data_URIs",
    "finalUrl": "https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Basics_of_HTTP/Data_URIs",
    "lighthouseVersion": "6.1.0",
    "userAgent": "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) HeadlessChrome/83.0.4103.93 Safari/537.36",
    "fetchTime": "2020-08-03T16:07:01.225Z",
    "environment": {
      "networkUserAgent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_14_6) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/84.0.4143.7 Safari/537.36 Chrome-Lighthouse",
      "hostUserAgent": "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) HeadlessChrome/83.0.4103.93 Safari/537.36",
      "benchmarkIndex": 674
    },
    "runWarnings": [],
    "configSettings": {
      "emulatedFormFactor": "desktop",
      "locale": "en-US",
      "onlyCategories": [
        "performance"
      ],
      "channel": "lr"
    },
    "audits": {
      "critical-request-chains": {
        "id": "critical-request-chains",
        "title": "Avoid chaining critical requests",
        "description": "The Critical Request Chains below show you what resources are loaded with a high priority. Consider reducing the length of chains, reducing the download size of resources, or deferring the download of unnecessary resources to improve page load. [Learn more](https://web.dev/critical-request-chains/).",
        "score": null,
        "scoreDisplayMode": "informative",
        "displayValue": "8 chains found",
        "details": {
          "type": "criticalrequestchain",
          "chains": {
            "A5325AC8B1B236F134BF51AA757298E3": {
              "children": {
                "26.14": {
                  "request": {
                    "url": "https://developer.mozilla.org/static/build/styles/l10n-survey.0eeb824ed1eb.css",
                    "responseReceivedTime": 463937.629765,
                    "startTime": 463937.613606,
                    "transferSize": 1436,
                    "endTime": 463937.629767
                  }
                },
                "26.5": {
                  "request": {
                    "transferSize": 1570,
                    "endTime": 463937.662484,
                    "url": "https://developer.mozilla.org/static/build/styles/auth-modal.be43f0f58a73.css",
                    "responseReceivedTime": 463937.662481,
                    "startTime": 463937.611824
                  }
                },
                "26.4": {
                  "request": {
                    "endTime": 463937.630225,
                    "startTime": 463937.611595,
                    "transferSize": 2284,
                    "responseReceivedTime": 463937.630223,
                    "url": "https://developer.mozilla.org/static/build/styles/react-header.78d662924939.css"
                  }
                },
                "26.12": {
                  "request": {
                    "endTime": 463937.634264,
                    "url": "https://developer.mozilla.org/static/build/styles/banners.e6cd46767c2e.css",
                    "responseReceivedTime": 463937.63426200004,
                    "startTime": 463937.613176,
                    "transferSize": 1376
                  }
                },
                "26.8": {
                  "request": {
                    "transferSize": 1829,
                    "startTime": 463937.612959,
                    "endTime": 463937.662893,
                    "responseReceivedTime": 463937.662891,
                    "url": "https://developer.mozilla.org/static/build/styles/prism.a6f275e5032b.css"
                  }
                },
                "26.6": {
                  "request": {
                    "endTime": 463937.650866,
                    "url": "https://developer.mozilla.org/static/build/styles/react-mdn.4e0ead71927e.css",
                    "responseReceivedTime": 463937.65086299996,
                    "startTime": 463937.612255,
                    "transferSize": 35533
                  }
                },
                "26.13": {
                  "request": {
                    "startTime": 463937.613339,
                    "endTime": 463937.629323,
                    "transferSize": 1508,
                    "url": "https://developer.mozilla.org/static/build/styles/mdn-subscriptions.dbb82432d74c.css",
                    "responseReceivedTime": 463937.62931999995
                  }
                },
                "26.7": {
                  "request": {
                    "transferSize": 1557,
                    "startTime": 463937.61266,
                    "responseReceivedTime": 463937.63605599996,
                    "endTime": 463937.636059,
                    "url": "https://developer.mozilla.org/static/build/styles/subscriptions.3cebf84de805.css"
                  }
                }
              },
              "request": {
                "url": "https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Basics_of_HTTP/Data_URIs",
                "transferSize": 61560,
                "responseReceivedTime": 463937.594315,
                "endTime": 463937.594317,
                "startTime": 463937.53046
              }
            }
          },
          "longestChain": {
            "transferSize": 1829,
            "duration": 132.43300002068281,
            "length": 2
          }
        }
      },
      "estimated-input-latency": {
        "id": "estimated-input-latency",
        "title": "Estimated Input Latency",
        "description": "Estimated Input Latency is an estimate of how long your app takes to respond to user input, in milliseconds, during the busiest 5s window of page load. If your latency is higher than 50 ms, users may perceive your app as laggy. [Learn more](https://web.dev/estimated-input-latency/).",
        "score": 1,
        "scoreDisplayMode": "numeric",
        "displayValue": "10 ms",
        "numericValue": 12.8
      },
      "total-byte-weight": {
        "id": "total-byte-weight",
        "title": "Avoids enormous network payloads",
        "description": "Large network payloads cost users real money and are highly correlated with long load times. [Learn more](https://web.dev/total-byte-weight/).",
        "score": 1,
        "scoreDisplayMode": "numeric",
        "displayValue": "Total size was 330 KiB",
        "details": {
          "type": "table",
          "headings": [
            {
              "itemType": "url",
              "text": "URL",
              "key": "url"
            },
            {
              "text": "Transfer Size",
              "itemType": "bytes",
              "key": "totalBytes"
            }
          ],
          "items": [
            {
              "url": "https://developer.mozilla.org/static/build/js/react-main.739f5d7ca4fd.js",
              "totalBytes": 93235
            },
            {
              "totalBytes": 61560,
              "url": "https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Basics_of_HTTP/Data_URIs"
            },
            {
              "url": "https://developer.mozilla.org/static/build/styles/react-mdn.4e0ead71927e.css",
              "totalBytes": 35533
            },
            {
              "url": "https://developer.mozilla.org/static/fonts/locales/ZillaSlab-Bold.subset.e96c15f68c68.woff2",
              "totalBytes": 34693
            },
            {
              "url": "https://developer.mozilla.org/static/fonts/locales/ZillaSlab-Regular.subset.bbc33fb47cf6.woff2",
              "totalBytes": 34437
            },
            {
              "totalBytes": 19085,
              "url": "https://www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js"
            },
            {
              "url": "https://developer.mozilla.org/static/build/js/react-bcd-signal.cf0fc711cfa2.js",
              "totalBytes": 8283
            },
            {
              "url": "https://cdn.speedcurve.com/js/lux.js?id=108906238",
              "totalBytes": 7537
            },
            {
              "url": "https://developer.mozilla.org/static/img/web-docs-sprite.22a6a085cf14.svg",
              "totalBytes": 4019
            },
            {
              "url": "https://developer.mozilla.org/static/build/styles/react-header.78d662924939.css",
              "totalBytes": 2284
            }
          ]
        },
        "numericValue": 337833
      },
      "speed-index": {
        "id": "speed-index",
        "title": "Speed Index",
        "description": "Speed Index shows how quickly the contents of a page are visibly populated. [Learn more](https://web.dev/speed-index/).",
        "score": 0.99,
        "scoreDisplayMode": "numeric",
        "displayValue": "0.8 s",
        "numericValue": 775.287095961904
      },
      "mainthread-work-breakdown": {
        "id": "mainthread-work-breakdown",
        "title": "Minimizes main-thread work",
        "description": "Consider reducing the time spent parsing, compiling and executing JS. You may find delivering smaller JS payloads helps with this. [Learn more](https://web.dev/mainthread-work-breakdown/)",
        "score": 1,
        "scoreDisplayMode": "numeric",
        "displayValue": "0.5 s",
        "details": {
          "type": "table",
          "headings": [
            {
              "itemType": "text",
              "text": "Category",
              "key": "groupLabel"
            },
            {
              "itemType": "ms",
              "key": "duration",
              "text": "Time Spent",
              "granularity": 1
            }
          ],
          "items": [
            {
              "duration": 171.94199999999989,
              "group": "scriptEvaluation",
              "groupLabel": "Script Evaluation"
            },
            {
              "group": "styleLayout",
              "groupLabel": "Style & Layout",
              "duration": 118.24500000000002
            },
            {
              "group": "other",
              "groupLabel": "Other",
              "duration": 89.691999999999837
            },
            {
              "groupLabel": "Rendering",
              "duration": 32.649999999999984,
              "group": "paintCompositeRender"
            },
            {
              "groupLabel": "Parse HTML & CSS",
              "duration": 28.025000000000002,
              "group": "parseHTML"
            },
            {
              "duration": 16.613,
              "group": "scriptParseCompile",
              "groupLabel": "Script Parsing & Compilation"
            },
            {
              "group": "garbageCollection",
              "groupLabel": "Garbage Collection",
              "duration": 2.731
            }
          ]
        },
        "numericValue": 459.89799999999968
      },
      "screenshot-thumbnails": {
        "id": "screenshot-thumbnails",
        "title": "Screenshot Thumbnails",
        "description": "This is what the load of your site looked like.",
        "score": null,
        "scoreDisplayMode": "informative",
        "details": {
          "type": "filmstrip",
          "items": [
            {
              "timing": 300,
              "timestamp": 463937829358,
              "data": "data:image/jpeg;base64,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"
            },
```

with the screenshot/data url being at the very bottom, it appears that the try catch may be hitting the catch but i cant tell why, does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Because `+` is for adding numbers not concatenating text.  PHP is not JS.  Also, depending on how its returned you probably need to `urlencode($url)`.

Comment: @AbraCadaver Ahh okay that makes sense, im still learning PHP and came from JS, what is the proper syntax then, is it ${URL} or {$URL}?

Comment: The second one inside of double quotes, or concat with `.` as in `url=" . $url . "&key` which you will need if you encode it `url=" .urlencode($url) . "&key`

Comment: Okay the curl is no longer giving an error, is $googlepsdata['screenshot-thumbnails']['details']['data']; the proper way to fetch the data url inside what curl fetches?

Comment: Dunno, `print_r($googlepsdata);` and follow the tree.  You want to pass `true` to `json_decode` to get all arrays.

Comment: @AbraCadaver Okay thank you for your help! If you want to answer the question i will accept it!